# How to search a string in another string using CHARINDEX?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use CHARINDEX to search for a string in another string.

Sample of my code go like this:

```
declare @TypeBigAC char(3)
select @TypeBigAC='333'
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@TypeBigAC, [ACType Iata])<>0 THEN ' Big AC' ELSE ''
```

This piece of code works, however, I want to default @TypeBigAC to more than 1 value. For example, when the @TypeBigAC either '333' or '340' or '332' can be found in [ACType Iata] I want 'Big AC' to be returned.

How to do that?

Comment: Add some sample data of column `[ACType Iata]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of what you are asking, it sounds like you want something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('333',[ACType Iata]) > 0 THEN 'Big AC'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('340',[ACType Iata]) > 0 THEN 'Big AC'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('332',[ACType Iata]) > 0 THEN 'Big AC'
        ELSE ''
    END AS MyColumn
FROM
    [MyTable]
```

Comment: That can be an alternative way of doing it. Thank you Nicarus.